# design many-to-many relationship throwing org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I want to design a many-to-many relationship for students to choose courses. At first, I used the many-to-many relationship directly, and then reported an error. Because I am a novice, I am not very clear about the specific rules. I suspect that there cannot be two relationships between the two entities, so I changed to the following way of writing, but it still reported the same error. I think I did follow the tutorial, but I really dont know where is wrong. So I have to ask for help.Below is the code.

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"handler", "hibernateLazyInitializer"})
public class User {
    private int id;
    private int rid;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String salt;
    private String email;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "salt")
    public String getSalt() {
        return salt;
    }
    public void setSalt(String salt) {
        this.salt = salt;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "rid")
    public int getRid() {
        return rid;
    }
    public void setRid(int rid) {
        this.rid = rid;
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=UserCourse.class,mappedBy = "student")
    private List<UserCourse> ars;
    public List<UserCourse> getArs() {
        return ars;
    }
    public void setArs(List<UserCourse> ars) {
        this.ars = ars;
    }
}
```

**Course**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "handler","hibernateLazyInitializer" })
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="sid")
    private Subject subject;
    public Subject getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
    public void setSubject(Subject subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tid")
    private User user;
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=UserCourse.class,mappedBy = "course")
    private List<UserCourse> ars;
    public List<UserCourse> getArs() {
        return ars;
    }
    public void setArs(List<UserCourse> ars) {
        this.ars = ars;
    }
}
```

**UserCourse**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_course")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "handler","hibernateLazyInitializer" })
public class UserCourse {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "uid")
    private User student;
    public User getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(User student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cid")
    private Course course;
    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
}
```

and the error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ars)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.tz.mooc.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ars)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ars)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:488) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:455) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:227) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:343) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:461) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

finally I just create a table in db by myself, and treat the user-course table like normal to avoid "@ManyToMany". I think it is not a best way, and it looks confused. Maybe someone will give me the better answer. I think it is better to create a demo to test.